# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 0x80040154 with CLSID 29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for the past two days. Now Google only shows me links that I've already visited.

I get the following error:

```
    [COMException (0x80040154): La récupération de la fabrique de classes COM pour le composant avec le CLSID {29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7} a échoué en raison de l'erreur suivante : 80040154 Classe non enregistrée (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).]
    Default2.initSession() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\GestionDomino\Default.aspx.cs:45
    Default2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\GestionDomino\Default.aspx.cs:32
    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

I know there is some part of the stacktrace that is in french. That's because the server executing this code is a french server.

Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Domino.NotesSession lotusNoteSession;
        Domino.NotesDatabase localDatabase;
        Domino.NotesView specificView;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //authentifies the user
            checkAuthen();
            //opens the domino session
            initSession();
            //fill the gridview
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                FillgvVue();
            }
        }

        protected void initSession()
        {
            //opens the domino session
            lotusNoteSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
```

And the code continues. But I stopped copying it at the problematic line 
`lotusNoteSession = new Domino.NotesSession()`. This line triggers the error.

I tried registering Interop.Domino.dll with regsvr32.exe

The target cpu is already set to x86

What do I have to do?

Thanks in advance

---

Comment: In case you weren't aware; you have a password in cleartext posted. You may want to remove it and request revision scrubbing so its not available forever.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET _"request revision scrubbing"_ - I don't think that's done very often. If it were up to me at least, I'd respond with _"tough luck; change your passwords"_. Especially since Google indexes this site in mere seconds.

Comment: @CodeCaster True, but IIRC there were some meta posts indicating they would do it for stuff like this. Changing passwords is still a good idea.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET nah. That's a test password. It will be changed when the app will work.

Comment: Is your OS 64 bit? And what IBM Lotus software do you have installed on the machine? Notes client, or Domino server? What version?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit. And it has Domino Server installed on it. It's version 9.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to register nlsxbe.dll properly, too. I'm pretty sure that I've seen posts that cover this here on StackOverflow before, but I'm not finding them now.

However, as per this [IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291), the Notes COM classes that are in nlsxbe.dlll and are behind the Interop.Domino.dll are not supported on a 64 bit OS. They can be made to mostly work, but if you need a solution that you can count on being able to go to IBM for support with if you encounter problems, you should look at the other APIs that are available for the Notes/Domino environment and avoid COM, or find a way to run them on a 32-bit OS.

As for the "mostly" part, the problems that I recall are with the methods that return collections of design elements (e.g., NotesDatabase.Views()). Most classes and methods did appear to work - including those that return individual elements (e.g., getView()). But again, there's no official support for these classes on 64 bits, so if you encounter any other problems you'll be on your own.